# Autofac integration with Mobile Azure Service

Tags: c#, autofac, azure-mobile-services

I have created Mobile Azure Service project and integrated it with the Autofac.

Here is my `IocConfig.cs` in which I have registered all ApiControllers and libs.

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

//Register API controllers
containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(UserController).Assembly);

/*Register Libs*/
containerBuilder.RegisterType<UserLib>().As<IUserLib>();
/*Register ObjectContexts*/
containerBuilder.RegisterType<MobileServiceContext>()
                .As<DbContext>().InstancePerDependency();

var container = containerBuilder.Build();
// var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

//For Web API dependency resolver
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

return container;
```

But Api is not calling due to some issue and throws an error `Controller is not registered`.

If I put below code, than it work fine, but it is a simple dependency:

```
var options = new ConfigOptions(); 
var builder = new ConfigBuilder(options, (httpConfig, autofac) => 
    autofac.RegisterInstance(new UserLib(new MobileServiceContext())).As<IUserLib>());

HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(builder);
```

Here is WebApiConfig , In which ServiceConfigurations are Done.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
        ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();

        // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));

        // To display errors in the browser during development, uncomment the following
        // line. Comment it out again when you deploy your service for production use.
        // config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MobileServiceContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());
    }
}
```

Code that calls the IocConfig method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    WebApiConfig.Register(); 
    IocConfig.RegisterDependencies(); 
    DatabaseConfig.InitializeDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Thanku For the Edition.. if you have Any Solution.please Provide

Comment: Have you ensured that your method in IocConfig is actually called on start up?

Comment: yes i have ensured that, and also checked that all components are properly registered.

Comment: Can you show your code where you call the method in `IocConfig`?

Comment: Protected void Application_Start() 
{
 WebApiConfig.Register(); IocConfig.RegisterDependencies(); DatabaseConfig.InitializeDatabase(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my Ioc Config with related services. It is now working.

```
public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        try
        {
            // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
            ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();

            // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
            HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options, (configuration, builder) =>
            {
                //Register API controllers
                builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(UserController).Assembly);

                /*Register Libs*/
                builder.RegisterType<UserLib>().As<IUserLib>();

                /*Register ObjectContexts*/
                builder.RegisterType<MobileServiceContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerDependency();

                /*Register DataRepository Here*/
                builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DataRepository<>)).As(typeof(IDataRepository<>));
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution. Could you mark your answer as accepted ? it will helps other people with similar issue resolving theirs